# Is it possible to handle support for multiple variations of the same language with BlackBerry API 7.x?

Tags: blackberry, internationalization, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm working with BlackBerry API 7.1 on Eclipse and I want to know if it's possible to add localization for variations of the same language.

I'm working on an app that needs to be localized for 10 countries that speak Spanish, but every country uses different manners of speech.

The problem I'm seeing is that [BlackBerry API 7.x's Locale class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/Locale.html) only has constants for Spain Spanish and Mexican Spanish. Does that mean localization for Spanish speaking countries such as Panama, Argentina, Colombia, etc. get a default localization as if it were Spain Spanish?

Also for this case where multiple variations of the same languages must be dealt with, how should I name the files? I tried adding locale_es-AR.rrc but the - is not admissible on Resource files names, but I don't know if locale_es_AR.rrc is the correct format.

I want to know before adding ten Resource files for these countries that may or may not be usable.

Is it possible what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying is correct. Have a look at [Localizing Your Files](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Creating_resource_files_655977_11.jsp)

> This file must have the same name as the resource header file,
>   followed by an underscore (_) and the language code, and then,
>   optionally, by a single underscore (_) and a country code (for
>   example, AppName_en_GB.rrc).

Comment: Great, but I also have the doubt on setting the default Locale, there's the method `Locale.get(string, string)`, which seems different from the method that uses int values that should be one of the Locale language constants. Does this method let me load any variation of a language even if it is not defined by the Locale constants?

Comment: You don't set any locale. It is automatic. You use ResourceBundle and it automatically takes care of the default locale. The default locale is set by the user by choosing the language settings.

Comment: but then, is it bad practice to use the Locale method setDefault(Locale) to set a different language than the one on the device?